# implementing LIN protocol on stm32

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

I am looking for implementing LIN protocol by STM32CUBEMX and I have searched all over the web and there are some documents and source code.
Is there anyone who has implemented LIN Bus listener project by STM32CUBEMX?
Best Regards

Comment: lin is supported by the hardware

Comment: The uart hardware module can be run in LIN mode. The HAL Layer from ST also has special functions to control the LIN settings. Should be easy to get a listener running.

Comment: I haven't found nothing related but some old and hard to understand codes